# Presence of parentheses suddenly causes code to break

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, office-2007

I had a line of VBA code that basically looked like this:

```
MyControls.Add(Factory.CreateMyControl(param1, param2))
```

Where `Factory.CreateMyControl` is just a sneaky way to allow the new instance of my class module being returned to have a constructor.

It was working without any issues for several weeks. Suddenly, it begins throwing the error `object doesn't support this property or method` which is baffling me because everything looks like it always has.

After stepping into and through the code, I finally narrowed it down to the line above, and found the issue. The issue was the pair of parentheses surrounding the parameter(s) for the Add function. When I changed the code to the following:

```
MyControls.Add Factory.CreateMyControl(param1, param2)
```

It worked just as it always had before the unexpected break.

I now understand that this is the basic syntax in VBA for calling `Sub`'s with parameters: to simply include all parameters in a comma-separated fashion without any parentheses (unless you're setting a `Function`'s return value to another variable or using it's value for some other purpose).

My real question is, why did this suddenly just stop working?
Is it a common occurrence using VBA in Office 2007 for code that once worked to break without warning?
Or could this have been caused by some kind of patch that happened without my knowledge?

Comment: Your original code should never have worked, and it should have looked like this: `MyControls.Add (Factory.CreateMyControl(param1, param2))` with a space before the first parenthesis.

Comment: Agreed with Rory it's hard to believe that the code ever worked that way, and of course, it is impossible for anyone to verify that it *was* working that way -- so, voting to close as "can no longer be reproduced".

Comment: @Rory Space or no space, it doesn't matter; the same result occurs. I guess I'm just confused as to why it would have ever let it work in the first place since I have absolutely not touched this part of my code for some time. And isn't this something that could have been caught by the IDE? It hardly seems like something that can't be detected until runtime. It's simple syntax.

Comment: Did you add a default property to whatever is being returned from `CreateMyControl` ?  That might have resulted in the parenthesis-wrapped version evaluating to something different (it would evaluate to the value of the default property and not the object itself)

Comment: @TimWilliams no default values, but good suggestion. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

With parentheses around, the `Sub`'s parameters per default were passed `ByVal` instead of `ByRef`. Without parentheses around, the default is `ByRef`

Example:

```
Dim r As Range

Sub test(v As Variant)
 MsgBox TypeName(v)
End Sub

Sub main()
 Set r = Range("A1")
 test r 'ByRef; TypeName is Range
 test (r) 'ByVal; TypeName is not Range but the type of the content of A1
End Sub
```